# JSF/PrimeFaces selectOneMenu change view-id

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm using JSF2 and PrimeFaces3. How can I write selectOneMenu that would invoke JSF navigation to redirect user to another page when he change option in menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attach an ajax listener and let it navigate by [`NavigationHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html).

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{navigator.outcome}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page..." />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="page1" itemLabel="Page 1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="page2" itemLabel="Page 2" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="page3" itemLabel="Page 3" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{navigator.navigate}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

*(the above example expects `page1.xhtml`, `page2.xhtml` and `page3.xhtml` in the same context; you can even make it a `<f:selectItems>` instead)*

with

```
private String outcome;

public void navigate() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, outcome + "?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

The `?faces-redirect=true` is not necessary, but it effectively sends a redirect so that the URL in browser address bar will properly change which is better for user experience and bookmarkability of the pages.

Comment: I haven't seen the comment(I don't know why), otherwise I wouldn't have commented...

Comment: @spauny: I'm not sure what you mean. Don't you mean to say "answer" instead of "comment"? Well, if you feel that your answer is superfluous, just delete it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant answer... My answer it's not totally superfluous; it says also about navigation with `redirect` instead of `navigationHandler` :D

Answer (score 2):

You could have something like:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.mySelectedPage}">
           <f:selectItem itemValue="http://www.yahoo.com" itemLabel="yahoo"  />
           <f:selectItem itemValue="http://www.google.com" itemLabel="google" />
           <f:selectItem itemValue="search.jsf" itemLabel="search" />
           <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.myNavigationMethod}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and on your navigationMethod you have:

```
String myPage = mySelectedPage
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(myPage);
```

The first two `selectItem` are for a full url and the last one is for another page in your web application(be careful that the extension must be the one set in your web.xml - it could be .jsf, .xhtml, .htm etc)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ajax navigation use the following:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{navigator.outcome}" onchange="window.location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">                      
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page..." />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page1" itemLabel="Page 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page2" itemLabel="Page 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page3" itemLabel="Page 3" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{navigator.navigate}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This works even if the session times out.

Comment: I tried using the ajax method but once the session times out you are left with a menu which doesnt respond to anything.

Comment: Note that OP explicitly asked "invoke JSF navigation". Perhaps he really need to do it programmatically, e.g. because he needs to keep track of pages for breadcrumbs/history and so on.