# How to make redirect using navigation-rule

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, navigation

A Redirect from Bean in JSF can be done by

```
externalContext.redirect("foo.xhtml");
```

But I want to use the rules, set in `<navigation-rule/>` (faces-config.xml) for `<from-outcome/>` && pass command line arguments.

```
externalContext.redirect("from-outcome?param=bar");
```

Is not working. How to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ExternalContext#redirect()` [takes an URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29), not a navigation outcome.

You need to return navigation outcomes from action methods declared to return `String`.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "from-outcome";
}
```

You can configure the navigation case to send a redirect by adding `<redirect>`.

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>from-outcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/foo.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect>
            <view-param>
                <name>param</name>
                <value>bar</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Note that you can also just make use of JSF implicit navigation without the need for this XML mess:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "/foo.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&param=bar";
}
```

If you're inside an event or ajax listener method which can't return a string outcome, then you could always grab `NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()` to perform the desired navigation.

```
public void someEventListener(SomeEvent event) { // AjaxBehaviorEvent or ComponentSystemEvent or even just argumentless.
    // ...

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, "from-outcome");
}
```

The non-navigation-case equivalent for that is using `ExternalContext#redirect()`.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, but how do I modify the value in the navigation-rule from the bean?

Comment: You can use EL in `<value>` like so `<value>#{bean.param}</value>`. This is equivalent to `return "/foo.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&param=" + URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");` (although some Mojarra versions have bugs with charset being used).

Comment: Thanks, I understand. But to come back to my question: So there is no way to use `navigation-rule` without returning a String? Because there are situations where this is not possible. What to do, if I want redirect from an Ajax call? There I can not return the navigation as String or am I wrong?

Comment: Use `ExternalContext#redirect()` with a true URL then. You can convert a navigation outcome to a true URL using `ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()`.

Comment: If I give a value of `from-outcome` to `ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()` I get a `IllegalArgumentException`. It says, it has to start with "/". but if I do so, the navigation rule is not used. Perhaps I should start a new question and show what I did? Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Sorry, I seriously mixed up things here (I'm a fan of implicit navigation where view ID is exactly the same as outcome, which eliminates code duplication; I never really used XML navigation cases, `getBookmarkableURL()` takes a view ID, not an XML outcome), you should use `NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530651/jsf-call-backing-bean-method-without-rendering-the-page-using-url-parameters/13530836#13530836 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255472/jsf-primefaces-selectonemenu-change-view-id/8256339#8256339

Comment: I updated the answer with an example specifically for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. That does the job! Now one last thing would be open, then this answer copes all needs I think: How do I get the navigation outcome as string? So like `ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()` but with a navigation rule, not view ID. This is for example needed, if I use primefaces `DefaultTagCloudItem`. It takes the URL as String for the Tag Cloud.

Comment: Cast `Application#getNavigationHandler()` to `ConfigurableNavigationHandler`, then you'll be able to call `getNavigationCase()` on it which in turn has among others `getBookmarkableURL()`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks, I think now I can handle all navigation related tasks!

Comment: With no parameters being included in redirect, just add `<redirect></redirect>` to the `<navigation-case>` node.